# how to add slug argument to url in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I want to add slug in url using django like this `<a href="{% url 'tutorials:tutorial' topic.tutorial_category.slug topic.tutorial_topic_category.slug topic.slug %} </a>`  i dont really know how to pass in triple slug in the url for example: i want to access the **programming > html > introduction-to-html** like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/tutorial/programming/html/introduction-to-html`

Error

```
Reverse for 'tutorial' with arguments '('', 'html', 'introduction-to-html')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['tutorial/(?P<main_category_slug>[^/]+)/(?P<topic_category_slug>[^/]+)/(?P<tutorial_slug>[^/]+)$']
```

topic.html:

```html
{% for topic in topics %}
     <a href="{% url 'tutorials:tutorial' topic.tutorial_category.slug topic.tutorial_topic_category.slug topic.slug %}">{{topic.title}} - Start Now</a>    

{% endfor %}
```

views.py:

```py
def topic(request, main_category_slug, topic_category_slug):
    tutorial_category = TutorialCategory.objects.get(slug=main_category_slug)
    tutorial_topic_category = TutorialTopicCategory.objects.get(slug=topic_category_slug)
    topics = Topic.objects.filter(tutorial_topic_category=tutorial_topic_category)

    context = {
        'topics':topics,
    }
    return render(request, 'tutorials/topic.html', context)

def tutorial(request, main_category_slug, topic_category_slug, tutorial_slug):
    tutorial_category = TutorialCategory.objects.get(slug=main_category_slug)
    tutorial_topic_category = TutorialTopicCategory.objects.get(slug=topic_category_slug)
    topics = Topic.objects.filter(tutorial_topic_category=tutorial_topic_category)
    tutorial = Topic.objects.get(slug=tutorial_slug)


    context = {
        'topics':topics,
        'tutorial':tutorial,
    }
    return render(request, 'tutorials/tutorial.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
  path("<slug>", views.tutorial_topic_category, name='tutorial-topic-category'),
        path("<slug:main_category_slug>/<slug:topic_category_slug>", views.topic, name='topic'),
        path("<slug:main_category_slug>/<slug:topic_category_slug>/<slug:tutorial_slug>/", views.tutorial, name='tutorial'),
```

models.py

```
class TutorialCategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    

class TutorialTopicCategory(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    tutorial_category = models.ForeignKey(TutorialCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)


class Topic(models.Model):
    tutorial_topic_category = models.ForeignKey(TutorialTopicCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, if you don't give anything in route while defining in path() as you give `"<main_category_slug>/<topic_category_slug>/<tutorial_slug>"` so these are considered strings.

For example: `<str:name>/` and `<name>/` is same.

If you want to make slugs all of three, so you should define them as slug first, write your route as `"<slug:main_category_slug>/<slug:topic_category_slug>/<slug:tutorial_slug>/"`, then these is considered as slugs.

Minor Mistake: You should not define same variables, it must be `for topic in topics` not  <s>`for topic in topic`</s>.

> `Note:` Always give `/` at the end of every route.

## Edit:

You should do following things in your code:

Firstly, change this link:

```html
<a href="{% url 'tutorials:tutorial' topic.tutorial_category.slug topic.tutorial_topic_category.slug topic.slug %}">{{topic.title}} - Start Now</a>
```

To this link:

```html
<a href="{% url 'tutorials:tutorial' topic.tutorial_topic_category.tutorial_category.slug topic.tutorial_topic_category.slug topic.slug %}">{{topic.title}} - Start Now</a>
```

### Why?

Look at your url correctly:

```py
 path("<slug:main_category_slug>/<slug:topic_category_slug>/<slug:tutorial_slug>/", views.tutorial, name='tutorial')
```

It's first slug is `main_category_slug` that means slug of `TutorialCategory` model which is at the first in *models.py*. So, for accessing you need to write `topic.tutorial_topic_category.tutorial_category.slug` in the template *tutorial.html*.

It's second slug is `topic_category_slug` that means `slug` of `TutorialTopicCategory` model which is at the second in *models.py*. So, for accessing it, you need to write `topic.tutorial_topic_category.slug` in the template *tutorial.html*.

It's third slugs is `tutorial_slug` that means your `slug` of `Topic` model which is at the last in *models.py*. So, for accessing it, you need to write `topic.slug` simply, in the template *tutorial.html*.

#### Simply change this and don't change anything:

topic.html or template file:

```html
{% for topic in topics %}

    <a href="{% url 'tutorials:tutorial' topic.tutorial_topic_category.tutorial_category.slug topic.tutorial_topic_category.slug topic.slug %}">{{topic.title}} - Start Now</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: tnx for your response, i learn something new. Now how can i pass the alug in a clickable link `<a href="{% url 'tutorials:tutorial'  what-should-put-here-as-slug-arguments %}">`

Comment: @DestinyFranks You need to put three slugs, as you put that was right, what problem do you exactly facing now?

Comment: this is the error i am facing now `Reverse for 'tutorial' with arguments '('', 'html', 'introduction-to-html')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['tutorial/(?P<main_category_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(?P<topic_category_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(?P<tutorial_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']`

Comment: @suderman-dubey this is how my url is looking now `<a href="{% url 'tutorials:tutorial' topic.tutorial_category.slug topic.tutorial_topic_category.slug topic.slug %}">`

Comment: @DestinyFranks  Have you changed the variable names `for topic in topics` not `for topic in topic`, and also change it in `context` of your `tutorial` view?